# Create mock tests for the Sitecore logic

Tags: unit-testing

Have anyone used Mock Test framework for unit testing? I need to perform an unit testing for parent child functionality and am not able to get it resolved, because i am not getting a parent child relationships using Mock setup. Please help me on the same. I need to mock an entire hierarchy level of parent and children

I have an article category section, which has different articles in it. I need to get all the articles, with the category name and the code logic is working fine. But I need to create a mock parent child relation setup for the same so that i can unit test that too.

Please help on this

Comment: Please create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example to show what you've already done. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

Using **Sitecore.FakeDb** you can create something like this:

```
    public void YourTest()
    {
        using (var db = GetHierarchyItems())
        {
           <.. run your testing here..>
        }
    }

    private static Db GetFullBreadcrumbsItems()
    {
        return new Db
        {
            new DbItem("Parent", ID.NewID, IConstants.WhateverTemplateId)
            {
                new DbItem("Child", ID.NewID, IConstants.WhateverTemplateId)
                {
                    new DbItem("Grandchild", ID.NewID, IConstants.WhateverTemplateId)
                },
                new DbField("Some Field Of Parent Item", IConstants.SomeFieldId)
                {
                     Value = "something"
                },
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: actually I just checked the documentation for Sitecore.FakeDb and they have a similar example: https://github.com/sergeyshushlyapin/Sitecore.FakeDb/wiki/Creating-a-Hierarchy-of-Items

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately it depends on what type of item/class you are passing into your code or logic in order to make it truly "testable" and what that `parent child relationship` really is.

[Sitecore.FakeDb](https://github.com/sergeyshushlyapin/Sitecore.FakeDb) is a great tool for faking Sitecore data where you are simply not able to avoid proper Sitecore `Items`.  When you *can* avoid using Sitecore `Items` in your code, when they translate to more generic classes like POCOs or DTOs, you can use mocking frameworks like [Moq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/moq/) (but there are literally hundreds of mocking frameworks out there). I had wrote a [post](https://vandsh.github.io/sitecore/2018/01/10/unit-testing-sitecore.html) a while back covering unit testing and mocking:

The below snippet is an example when you can *try* and avoid using Items (illustrated using a test around search):

```
[Test]
[Category("UnitTest")]
public void ExecuteSearchQuery()
{
    //the search context most often will just be the sitecore search context 
    //but could be outside of sitecore
    var mockSearchProvider = new Mock<IProviderSearchContext>();

    //the search repository consumes the provider which most often 
    //will be sitecore but could be another provider and another mechanism 
    var mockSearchRepository = new Mock<ISearchRepository>();

    //the search service instance we want to mock
    var searchService = new SearchService(mockSearchProvider.Object, 
                                               mockSearchRepository.Object);

    //mock the repository
    var mockResultsList = new List<SearchHit<SearchResult>>();
    mockResultsList.Add(new SearchHit<SearchResult>(1, new SearchResult()
    {
        Content = "test",
        CreatedBy = "admin",
        CreatedDate = DateTime.MinValue,
        DatabaseName = "web",
        Datasource = null,
        ExcludeFromSearch = false,
        FullLinkToItem = "http://linktoitem",
        IsPage = true
    }));

        var mockSearchResults = new SearchResults<SearchResult>(mockResultsList, 1);

    mockSearchRepository
        .Setup(ss => ss.Search(mockSearchProvider.Object, 
                                        It.IsAny<string>(), 
                                        It.IsAny<int>(), 
                                        It.IsAny<int>()))
        .Returns(mockSearchResults);

    //test the rest of the search using the mocked provider
    var searchResultsDto = searchService.SiteSearch("test", 1, 10);

    //assert
    searchResultsDto.Hits.Count().Should().Be(1);
}
```

To summarize the above, the `mockSearchProvider` and `mockSearchRepository` are proper Sitecore interfaces that have been mocked, the `searchService` is the logic we are covering in the test, and the `mockResultsList` is a generic `List<>` of items that will be used to drive what would normally be the results from something like the `Content Search API`.

If you simply can't avoid a direct reference to a Sitecore `Item`, you can mock using `Sitecore.FakeDb` like @ellele's answer above:

```
[Test]
[Category("UnitTest")]
public void TestYourClassLogic()
{
    //setup
    var testArticle1 = new DbItem("testArticle1", ID.NewID, IArticleConstant.TemplateId);
    var testArticle2 = new DbItem("testArticle1", ID.NewID, IArticleConstant.TemplateId);
    var parent = new DbItem("testArticleSection") { testArticle1, testArticle2 };
    var _db = new Db(){parent};

    //test the innerds of the YourClass (the class you have your logic in) that actually calls .GetItem...
    var _mockSitecoreContext = new Mock<ISitecoreContext>();
    _mockSitecoreContext.Setup(sc => sc.Database).Returns(_db.Database);
    var yourClass = new YourClass(_mockSitecoreContext.Object);
    var result = tagHelper.YourLogicDoSomethingOnThisArticle(testArticle1.ID);

    result.Should().Be("ExpectedValue");

    //teardown
    _db.Dispose();
}
```

Why did I cover search in this post when that's not the OP's question/situation? It's the thing I see in most sites, with the most complexity and the easiest to relate to. My end goal is to just show that if you can avoid depending on the `Item` directly, mocking and unit testing will almost always be easier (but not always unavoidable). The second thing I wanted to illustrate is that in order to really prove things to be "testable" you need to mock Sitecore layers/services/APIs and likely refactor your own code in order to make it testable. Unit testing done right is not an easy checkbox to fill.

I really hope this helps.